# Can we make an android app which works as a mouse for a computer

Tags: java, android

We plan to make an android application which works as a mouse for a computer. We are stuck in the middle. We want to know how to return the coordinate value to the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes Here is the sample application for that 
   [Remote Mouse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hungrybolo.remotemouseandroid).
2. You will need a server which is hosted on the computer. Server will play a role of communication between android app and Computer.